# How to arrange Circles to make Trinity in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, geometry

The desired [outcome](https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/712/464/png-clipart-borromean-rings-trinity-triquetra-symbol-ring-love-christianity-thumbnail.png)

Using

```swift
ZStack {
    Circle()
        .frame(width: width * 0.73, height: width * 0.2)
    
    Circle()
        .frame(width: width * 0.73, height: width * 0.2)
    
    Circle()
        .frame(width: width * 0.73, height: width * 0.2)
}
```

Don't care about details here, but the position of circles. Because if we offset two circles one by -10 and other by 10 in y axis, and move up the third circle in x axis by 10, it no longer perfectly centers.

Please help, what's the math in forming a perfect trinity using Circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code displays a `trinity` in a view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let radius = CGFloat(222)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 4)
                .offset(CGSize(width: -radius/4, height: radius/2))
            
            Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 4)
            
            Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 4)
                .offset(CGSize(width: radius/4, height: radius/2))
        }
         .frame(width: radius, height: radius)
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

to highlight the important part, the `.frame(width: radius, height: radius)` of the `ZStack`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Trinity")
            TrinityView(radius: CGFloat(123))
        }
        .frame(width: 333, height: 333)
    }
}

struct TrinityView: View {
    let radius: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 4).offset(x: -radius/4, y: radius/2)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 4)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Circle().stroke(lineWidth: 4).offset(x: radius/4, y: radius/2)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }.frame(width: radius, height: radius)
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain the trigonometry here little bit?

Comment: in the `ZStack`, the second Circle is the centre circle, located at (0,0) in the `.frame(width: radius, height: radius)`. The first Circle is just
 `r/4` to the left and `r/2` down. The third Circle, is `r/4` to the right and `r/2` down
 from the center circle.
 Note you could also use the simpler form: `.offset(x: radius/4, y: radius/2)` etc... The main part is the ZStack frame.

Comment: The term radius here may be a bit confusing at first sight, because what you are actually referring to is the circle's diameter, not its radius.

Comment: yes, absolutely correct, it should be diameter, or at least the width/height of the frame.